# Android Publisher Google Console API is not returning list of reviews

Tags: android, google-api, google-play-services, android-package-managers, google-play-developer-api

Based on [google documentation](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/rest/v3/reviews/list), I am calling the endpoint for fetching all reviews like here:

```
curl \
'https://androidpublisher.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v3/applications/com.questionpro/reviews' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer [myAccessToken] \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --compressed
```

but this endpoint returns an empty objec {}, like there is no review to fetch but there are:

[Click here to see public reviews that I want to fetch](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.questionpro&hl=en_IN&gl=US)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you check the doucmenation for [Retrieving a set of reviews](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/reply-to-reviews#retrieving_a_set_of_reviews) you will find it states.

[image]

Which implies to me that you have no new reviews in the last week so that is why your getting an empty object. If you want all the reviews then your going to have to download the cvs file via play store.  This can not be done via the api.

Comment: Is this something new or it always has been acting like that? Because I remember when implementing the API myself that it used to return the last 100 reviews with `tokenPagination` for the next page and so on..

Comment: Cant tell you its been this way as long as I can remember.

Comment: Really? Because i've been building a Node.js app that interacts with this API maybe 6 months ago and the returned data was completely different. It was returning tokenPagination and also returned the last 100 results.. Maybe something with the call has been changed? Maybe I am sending something wrong?

Comment: It probably will return a next page token if you have more rows over the course of a week.   Unfortunately they aren't showing a change log for that api so its going to be hard to know for sure.  I dont have any contacts on that team either so cant contact anyone

Comment: Yeah I also searched for the change log, but couldn't find it. I am pretty sure that few months ago, when calling to this API i've got the last 100 results with a tokenPagination for the next page and so on. If I wanted, I could've pulled all the reviews, but something has changed.